# R package gsl problems when downloading in Rstudio

Tags: r, gsl

I need to download a package that apparently needs gsl installed beforehand. I am using Rstudio with R version 3.6 on Windows. When I try to install it using install.packages() I get this message:

> Installing package into ‘(my library)’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> installing *source* package 'gsl' ...
> package 'gsl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> using staged installation
>
> ---
>
> WARNING: this package has a configure script
> It probably needs manual configuration
>
> ---
>
> libs
>
> arch - i386
> C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I/include         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c airy.c -o airy.o
> airy.c:1:29: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h: No such file or directory
> #include <gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h>
> ^
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: airy.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gsl'
> removing 'C:/Users/...'
> restoring previous 'C:/Users/...'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘C:/Users/.../gsl_2.1-7.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I found this thread with the same error message but I tried doing the same procedure as @tchevrier and the same result keeps coming up.

I found this thread with the same error message but I tried doing the same procedure as @tchevrier and the same result keeps coming up as before doing anything.

Comment: I don't think R supports 32 bit architectures anymore. My foggy memory is telling me the change occurred  2-3 years ago. You may need to revert to a version that did have  32 bit option, or find a version gsl that is not dependent on that.

Comment: Hey, my computer is 64 bit but that is as far as my knowledge about this goes. What should I do to change it in R?

Comment: Why not install the binary from CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsl/index.html  (Since that was the most recent version of the source for gsl, I'm thinking the problem is that your Rtools installation is not synced up with you version of R.)

Comment: Oh wow! The binary version worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: I think I was wrong about no support for 32 bit arch in Windows. I checked the FAQ and The R Windows FAQ and could not find evidence for my foggy memories. There was evidence that Rstudio is no longer supporting 32 bit versions.